# Render component of nested routes ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have nested routes that go 3 levels deep but I'm not able to render the component of my last route. This is how I structured my routes :

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <Router history={browserHistory}>
   <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
   <Route path="/" name="test" component={requireAuthentication(App)}>
     <Route path="/modules" name="Modules" component={Modules}>
       <Route path="virtual-inputs" name="Virtual Inputs" component={VirtualInput}>
         <Route path="add" name="Add new virtual input" component={AddVirtualInput}/>
       </Route>
     </Route>
   </Route>
 </Router>
</Provider>
```

When I go to modules/virtual-inputs/add I get my component VirtualInput rendered.

I render inside modules my child components with this.props.children, but how can I render my component AddVirtualInput when going to /modules/virtual-inputs/add ?

I saw already on another thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33690586/846326) that another solution is to have my routes like this :

```
<Route path="/modules" name="Modules" component={Modules}>
  <Route path="virtual-inputs" name="Virtual Inputs" component={VirtualInput}/>
  <Route path="virtual-inputs/add" name="Add new virtual input" component={AddVirtualInput}/>
</Route>
```

Is this the way to do it, meaning we can't go further then 2 levels?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction on the level of nesting of routes in React Router.

When you nest routes, the parent route component will receive the current matching child route component as `this.props.children`. As long as you don’t forget to use `this.props.children`, they should render just fine.

In your case, it should be enough to make sure that you use `this.props.children` in the `render()` method of the `VirtualInput` component. Otherwise it will receive `AddVirtualInput` in `this.props.children` but you won’t see it since it doesn’t get rendered.

If you already did that, please share the full code of the components to further diagnose the issue.

Comment: I'm doing {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props })} in my parent components Modules and VirtualInput but when going to one of my child components is resulting in Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. I have another example where I have exactly the same issue. See : https://gist.github.com/DriesS/b72dce81113b8c5cc374

Comment: If you do `{React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ...this.props })}`, you are effectively passing `children` as a prop to the `children` themselves, thus creating an infinite hierarchy. Why do you need `React.cloneElement()` there? You can render `this.props.children` directly. If you really need to pass all props down (Why? I don’t see you using them), you can do something like `var { children, ...rest } = this.props;` and then `React.cloneElement(children, rest)`. I still don’t understand why though.